# NoClassDefFoundError for a packaged class

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to run a jar file that uses the YouTube Data API and I'm getting a NoClassDefFoundError for one of the API classes:

[alt text http://img205.imageshack.us/img205/1808/noclassdeffounderror.png](http://img205.imageshack.us/img205/1808/noclassdeffounderror.png)

AuthenticationException.class is found in the gdata-core-1.0 jar:

[alt text http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/7329/authenticationexception.png](http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/7329/authenticationexception.png)

The gdata-core-1.0 jar has been added to my classpath:

[alt text http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/2195/classpathe.png](http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/2195/classpathe.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why aren't you using Eclipse for your builds?

Comment: I'm new to Eclipse. I'm using it to compile automatically and make the jar but running the jar on the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may not be having the jar in the classpath. The command prompt execution does not set the classpath. You will have to either do it by yourselves or give it on the fly while executing.

You should probably take a look at setting the [MANIFEST](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/mod.html) file correct for the JAR file.

This [post](http://fraaargh.wordpress.com/2008/07/13/how-to-java-jars-and-manifestmf/) has a better description

Comment: It's highlighted in the last image

Comment: Yes, but the exception you're getting is in the command prompt and not in the Eclipse. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: The classpath created in Eclipse is in the the jar file that I try to run. Do I need to set it again in the command prompt?

Comment: Ah!! Got it!! There will be a file called MANIFEST.MF in the jar, you will have to set the classpath there!! See my updated answer